# Dropping/removing last/first row in each group R

Tags: r, group-by

Here is my dataframe:

```
categ <- c('a','a','a','b','b')
value <- c(1,2,5,4,5)
df <- data.frame(categ, value)
```

I would like to group by `categ` column and drop the first/last element in each group. Ideally I would like to create a column with indication of the first/last element in each group. Here is what I tried, but it did not work:

```
library('plyr')
ddply(df, .(categ), function(x) x[-nrow(x)])
```

P.S. This is probably duplicate question, but I am new to R and R is very cryptic, so I cannot port solutions immediately.

Comment: Very easy with *data.table* `setDT(df)[, value[-c(1L, .N)], by = categ]` or *dplyr* `slice(group_by(df, categ), -c(1, n()))`

Comment: Using `dplyr`, you can `df %>% group_by(categ) %>% filter(row_number() != 1 & row_number() != n())` to drop the first and last row in each group or `df %>% group_by(categ) %>% mutate(ind=ifelse(row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n(),1,0)` to create the indication column.

Comment: is your question solved, if so please mark it as solved.

Comment: @and I just did, sorry for delay. It takes time for me to read all solutions and understand them

Comment: no problem, its just that i was searching for question where i can help. and when it's already solved its good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the dplyr package instead. Following code drops the last element of each group.

```
    library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(categ) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(rank = 1:length(value)) %>% 
      dplyr::filter(rank < max(rank)) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(rank = NULL)
```

Comment: All answers were good, but I guess `dplyr` wins for readability.

Answer (score 24):

There is an even simpler solution using {dplyr} to drop the first row of each group:

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% 
       group_by(categ) %>% 
       slice(2:n())
```

For dropping last row of each group:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(categ) %>% 
    slice(1:(n()-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Think you were just missing a comma to signify that you wanted rows rather than the default for "[" which is column selection. For dropping the last row:

```
ddply(df, .(categ), function(x) x[-nrow(x), ])
```

Could also have used the `head`-function. For dropping the first item, the `tail` function can be substituted for `head`:

```
> ddply(df, .(categ), function(x) head(x ,-1) )
  categ value
1     a     1
2     a     2
3     b     4
```

Noting that `plyr` and `dplyr` don't play well together, I am now restarting R.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an indicator column for the first and last element per group, you could do this in base R:

```
df$indicator <- FALSE
```

For last element per group:

```
df$indicator[cumsum(rle(as.numeric(df$categ))$lengths)] <- TRUE

#  categ value indicator
#1     a     1     FALSE
#2     a     2     FALSE
#3     a     5      TRUE
#4     b     4     FALSE
#5     b     5      TRUE
```

Now if you want to drop the last element per group, you can simply do:

```
df[!df$indicator,]
```

---

For first element per group:

```
df$indicator[which(diff(c(0,as.numeric(df$categ)))==1)] <- TRUE

#  categ value indicator
#1     a     1      TRUE
#2     a     2     FALSE
#3     a     5     FALSE
#4     b     4      TRUE
#5     b     5     FALSE
```

Now if you want to drop the first element per group, you can simply do:

```
df[!df$indicator,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df, duplicated(categ))
i1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
i2 <- with(df, duplicated(categ, fromLast=TRUE))
i2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
df[i1, ]
#  categ value
#2     a     2
#3     a     5
#5     b     5

df[i2, ]
#  categ value
#1     a     1
#2     a     2
#4     b     4
```